# Whether it Library org.garret.prest?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-support-library, decompiler

I discovered this when decompiler an application, no one knows what it's kind of a Library? I found it in an Android app, because I want to look to try the library

[image]

Comment: What exactly is your problem?

Comment: I want to put it into the package org.garret.perst my application, but do not know where to get the package @iRuth

Comment: Did you try Googling this [up](https://www.google.com/search?q=org+garret+perst)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a database library called [Perst](http://www.mcobject.com/perst).

Comment: where can I get her library? to put into my application? @Lesleh

Comment: From the site linked in the answer.

Comment: you know how to open a file database .idx?